# Incorrect open multiselect list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click on the icon have to be opened only one list (which icon pressed). How can I do each list unique? Please help! In this code I use font-awesome, sorry about it, but I can't add it in this example.

```js
$(".filterBlock .filter-ico").on('click', function() {
  $(".filterDropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});


$(".filterDropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".filterDropdown dd ul").hide();
});


function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("filterDropdown")) $(".filterDropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.multiselect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliselect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
  title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.resultSelect').append(html);
    $(".resultFilter").hide();
} else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".resultFilter");
    $('.filterDropdown dt a').append(ret);

}
});
```

```css
.filters {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.filterBlock {
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filterBlock h3 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font: 16px Helvetica;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #5795f9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico.sphere {
  left: 190px;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico.show {
  left: 200px;
}
.filterDropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  transform: translateX(10%);
}
.filterDropdown a {
  color: #5795f9;
}
.filterDropdown dd,
.filterDropdown dt {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.filterDropdown ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.filterDropdown dd {
  position: relative;
}
.filterDropdown a,
.filterDropdown a:visited {
  color: #5795f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/*.filterDropdown dt a {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
 min-height: 15px;
 line-height: 24px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 0;
 width: 152px;
 border:1px solid black;
}*/

.filterDropdown dt a span,
.resultSelect span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #5795f9;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  /* padding: 0 6px 2px 0;*/
}
.filterDropdown dd ul {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #5795f9;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0.5, 0, 0);
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.filterDropdown span.value {
  display: none;
}
.filterDropdown dd ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.filterDropdown dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #5795f9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class = "filters">

      <div class = "filterBlock city">
        <h3>Регіон</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico city"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>

      <div class = "filterBlock sphere">
        <h3>Сфера діяльності</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico sphere"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>  
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Судова система">Судова система</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Прокуратура">Прокуратура</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>

      <div class = "filterBlock show">
        <h3>Показувати спочатку</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico show"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Осіб з більшим показником ризику">Осіб з більшим показником ризику</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Осіб з меньшим показником ризику">Осіб з меньшим показником ризику</li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Included font-awesome, can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @SergChernata when I click on icon there are 3 lists will open. I have to do that one click and one list. Thank you for including.

Comment: @SergChernata can you help me again please.. what I need to do that text which I chosed will write and will not close, when I press on icon

.

Comment: Start a new question.

Comment: @I done, if I will have a new questions I'll start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a mess. I got it this far, if you want more changes you'll have to specify.

```js
$(".filterBlock .filter-ico").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('dl').toggle('fast');
});


$(".filterDropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('dl').hide();
});


function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  //if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("filterDropdown")) $(".filterDropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.multiselect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliselect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
  title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.resultSelect').append(html);
    $(".resultFilter").hide();
} else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".resultFilter");
    $('.filterDropdown dt a').append(ret);

}
});
```

```css
.filters {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.filterBlock {
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filterBlock h3 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font: 16px Helvetica;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #5795f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico.sphere {
  left: 190px;
}
.filterBlock .filter-ico.show {
  left: 200px;
}
.filterDropdown {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  transform: translateX(10%);
}
.filterDropdown a {
  color: #5795f9;
}
.filterDropdown dd,
.filterDropdown dt {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.filterDropdown ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.filterDropdown dd {
  position: relative;
}
.filterDropdown a,
.filterDropdown a:visited {
  color: #5795f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/*.filterDropdown dt a {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
 min-height: 15px;
 line-height: 24px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 0;
 width: 152px;
 border:1px solid black;
}*/

.filterDropdown dt a span,
.resultSelect span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #5795f9;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  /* padding: 0 6px 2px 0;*/
}
.filterDropdown dd ul {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #5795f9;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0.5, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  border-top: none;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.filterDropdown span.value {
  display: none;
}
.filterDropdown dd ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.filterDropdown dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #5795f9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class = "filters">

      <div class = "filterBlock city">
        <h3>Регіон</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico city"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Київ">Київ</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>

      <div class = "filterBlock sphere">
        <h3>Сфера діяльності</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico sphere"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>  
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Судова система">Судова система</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Прокуратура">Прокуратура</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>

      <div class = "filterBlock show">
        <h3>Показувати спочатку</h3>

        <span class = "filter-ico show"><i class = "fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <dl class = "filterDropdown first">
          <dt>
            <a href=""> <span class = "resultFilter"></span></a>

            <p class = "resultSelect"></p>

          </dt>
          <dd>
            <div class = "multiselect">
              <ul>

                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Осіб з більшим показником ризику">Осіб з більшим показником ризику</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Осіб з меньшим показником ризику">Осіб з меньшим показником ризику</li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </dd>

        </dl>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This is not woking. :(

Comment: It's working for me. You need to be more specific. I already told you that.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Yes, it's working. Best answer..Thank a lot